# How to change matplotlibrc param files during run?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use multiple matplotlib parameter files to create matplotlib plots depending on the application. One set of configuration for publications, another for presentation, etc. I would like to do it by just changing the file path of the matplotlibrc parameter file as the program runs. How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is what the `style` module is for.  See [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) and  [api](http://matplotlib.org/api/style_api.html).

```
with plt.style.context(('dark_background')):
    plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)), 'r-o')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [`rc_context`](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_context).

This example is copied from the link above:

```
with mpl.rc_context(fname='screen.rc'):
    plt.plot(x, a)
    with mpl.rc_context(fname='print.rc'):
        plt.plot(x, b)
    plt.plot(x, c)
```

The settings loaded from a file are valid in the whole `with` block. All plotting that happens outside of this block uses the default `rc` parameters.

Comment: It seems it is clear for you what and where are the files 'screen.rc' and 'print.rc'. Also what 'a', 'b' and 'c' stand for. I have met the pertinent section referring to this "pseudo example" (you also refer to with your link)  in a dozen(s) of places. No one cares to explain what all this stuff is. Can you enlighten me/us?

Comment: The question is about how to cleanly use several style files. 'screen.rc' and 'print.rc' are paths to the style files. I guess x, a, b, c are not defined because they are not relevant to the point the authors of the example wanted to make. I agree that the example is probably not as good as it could be. Please feel free and improve my answer by editing it :-)

Comment: How can I improve your answer if I know less than you? :)) OK I will post a question on this. I am very curious what I would get as replies (if any).